# PROCESS Mediation Interpretation - indirect and direct

Tags: mediation

I'm an undergrad dumbass so please be gentle. I ran 6 models and my results were really strange.

1. Path B in all 6 of my models were non-sig. (Is this ok?)
2. However, 3 of my models had both total and direct effects that did not pass 0, but the indirect effects passed 0. (Is this partial mediation?)
3. Only 1 model had total, direct, and indirect paths that did not pass 0. (I'm assuming this one is full mediation)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If path B became non-significant after controlling for the mediator, that would be "full" mediation. Partial mediation occurs if the indirect effect does not include 0, and the B path remains significant (<.05).

If the indirect effect included 0 within the confidence interval, the null-hypothesis is retained and you don't have a significant indirect effect/ no mediation.

So, it sounds like you had one successful mediation model if the indirect effect didn't pass 0.

Comment: What do I say about the 3 models where only the total and direct didn't pass through 0? 

Thank you for your response!!!!

Comment: You can say that you don't have enough support to conclude that your total and direct effects are conditional on the mediator. Just because the indirect effect was non-significant, doesn't mean that there isn't one....it just means that in this model, you don't have the evidence to claim your significant total effect or direct effect is contingent on the presence of your mediator. I am guessing your a path or b path is non-significant as well? You can say that X effects Y. The results indicate that there is either no effect of mediation, or your sample size may be too small to detect it.

Comment: My a path was significant for all of them, just the b path wasn't. 

Also, when does partial mediation occur? I'm a bit confused about that.